# targeting divs with "left=0" css property

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-masonry

I am using masonry.js and i would like to add a class to the elements that are on the very left of the viewport. Since the plug-in put those elements not in a a specific order I've found it hard to Target them using the nth selector. I was wondering how to filter using Jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this is what you're looking for.

```
$('div').each(function(){
    if($(this).css('left') === "0px"){
        //This is where you get your desired div as "this"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('left') === '0px';
});
```

You have to filter all div's if you're searching for the one with specific css property.

Comment: Note that this will return an array of `div` elements. This is the most practical and clean solution I think. +1!

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('div selector').css('left') == '0' ){
     YOUR CODE GOES HERE
}
```

Comment: Use parseInt for safety, since `.css()` return results like 'nPx'

Comment: i need to target back only those elements with that specific property, add the class only to those divs with that "left=0" value, that is kinda tricky for me!

Comment: whats the property u looking for?

Comment: i need to target the divs with "left=0" and add a class with a padding-left of 10px, to be more specific

Comment: the ans i gave wil give u divs with left css property as 0, inside the if u can write your code, as in add class with padding-left as 10px

Comment: This is an error. The `$` returns you an array. You're comparing an array with literal.

Comment: $ is not an array, its a selector in jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

HTML

```
<div class="masonry_parent">
   <div class="masonry_child"></div>
   <div class="masonry_child"></div>
   <div class="masonry_child"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.masonry_parent .masonry_child').each(function(){
 if($(this).offset().left == $('.masonry_parent').offset().left)
 {
    $(this).addClass('classLeft');
 }
});
```